# Only last common character is getting deleted from string not all the common character

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I am trying to remove repeating common characters from a string but the problem is only the last common character which in this case is y is getting deleted and all the others common characters are displayed as they are. I am not getting any exception .

```
public class stringCompare {
private static String s;
private static char[] c;
private static boolean[] b;

public static void judge(boolean flag , int l){
    b[l] = flag;
}//judge

public static void main(String[] args) {

    s = "unlucky unlucky unlucky unlucky";
    c = new char[s.length()];
    b = new boolean[s.length()];
    int j;
    System.out.println(s.length());
    for(int i=0 ; i<s.length() ; i++){
        c[i] = s.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(c[i]);
         for(j=0 ; j<s.length() ; j++){
             System.out.println(c[j]);
             if(c[i] == s.charAt(j)){
                 judge(true , i);
             }//if
             else if(c[i] != s.charAt(j)){
                 judge(false , i);
             }//else if
         }//for
    }//for

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    for(int k=0 ; k<b.length ; k++){
        System.out.println(b[k] +"===="+k);
        if(b[k] == false){
            sb.append(c[k]);
        }//if
    }//for

    System.out.println(sb.toString());

 }//main

}//stringCompare

Output from the program -
 unluck unluck unluck unluck
```

But i was expecting output as - unlucky

Comment: What is a "repeating common character"?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen unlucky is repeating but as we can see we have five unlucky in the string collection. I thought since the whole string is repeating so only the first string will be displayed and all others are deleted.

Comment: instead it should be `delete repeating word`

Comment: So you want to detect substrings which has occurred already in the string and skip them when copying?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Yes sir but i am not allowed to use any generic method here

Comment: substrings, or words? Because `u` is a substring. And yet it appears twice in your expected output. Please define your problem clearly.

Comment: @ JB Nizet  Sir i am trying to get the substring

Comment: I think you should start with _detecting_ if a given substring already exists in the string.  Write code that prints out the locations of the word "luck" in your original string.

Answer (score 0):

**just try this Logic**

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
String s = "unlucky unlucky unlucky unlucky";
char[] inp_cpy=s.toCharArray();
for( char x : inp_cpy)
{
   if(!sb.ToString().Contains(""+x))
   {
   sb.append(x);
   }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: And what would this print for "abc cba"?

Answer (score 0):

This code prints "unlcky", that is, it removes all repeating characters. I understood that was your problem. If "indexOf" is not allowed then you should replace it with a loop that searches for a character in the string.

```
public class stringCompare {
    private static String s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        s = "unlucky unlucky unlucky unlucky";

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            String currentChar = s.substring(i,i+1);
            if (result.indexOf(currentChar)==-1) {
                result.append(currentChar);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinkedHashSet if ordering is a matter of concern, otherwise TreeSet or HashSet.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class StringCompare{
public static void main(String[] args) {

String s = "unlucky unlucky unlucky unlucky";
LinkedHashSet<Character> linkedhashset = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
     if(s.charAt(i) != ' ')
     linkedhashset.add(s.charAt(i));
     }
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linkedhashset.toArray()));
linkedhashset.forEach(System.out::print);
}
}
```

The ouput is:

```
[u, n, l, c, k, y] 
unlcky
```